# "Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?)." when running with Angular SSR

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular9

I have set up SSR for my Angular 9 project, and when I run `ng run <project-name>:serve-ssr`, I get this error: `Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).` When I run the project with `ng serve`, everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

I would share code, but I'm not sure which part is relevant. Please ask for samples if you need to see something, and I'll update this post.

Comment: The part for the `ApplicationModule` would help.

Answer (score 0):

I realised removing `"bundleDependencies": "none",` from `angular.json` did the trick, although I don't really understand the reasoning behind it

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with angular 9 SSR. I have made little structural changes in ts-config and web-pack config because I need my bundler to output server.js (compiled version of server.ts) at root. To validate if its a global problem or due to my structural changes I have set up a test project with angular universal SSR. It all works  in test project. Still trying to find the culprit. There is no "bundleDependencies": "none" in my angular.json file tho.